# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager' coming up even after trying everything

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver-manager

I was following the tutorial from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-all-text-of-the-page-using-selenium-in-python/) and it still says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'`, even after installing webdrivermanager in multiple ways, already recommended in other posts on stackoverflow. I tried `pip install webdriver-manager`, `pip install webdriver_manager` and `pip install webdrivermanager`, yet nothing seems to work.

Edit: It seems to work on my Laptop, so I think It could be a wrong install of the libary... any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: Have you tried doing everything using `pip3` instead of `pip`?

Comment: I did try to use pip3, also doing it in another IDE and in the cmd/terminal, but it didnt work

Comment: According to this [page on pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/), you need to run `pip install webdriver-manager` (with a `-` in between `webdriver` and `manager`). Have you tried that? What about with `pip3`?

Comment: @Mooncat, can you add `pip freeze` to your question?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I did just do that and it didnt work, it's still not recognized. I tried it in every possible way I could imagine

Comment: @sudden_appearance webdriver-manager==3.5.2

Comment: Does `python3 -m pip freeze` also have it. Are you running windows or *nix?

Comment: Yes it does have webdriver-manager 3.5.2, and I'm running windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling Python completely, and now it works, but still thanks for all the help!